# How do I avoid making methods and variables static in this code?

Tags: java, methods, static

I was solving past exams for my java class and I'm struggling with one of them. I keep getting wrong result and I think its because all of classes and instance variables are static. How do I avoid making them static? Also this question basically wants you to find same letters of the location given in args[1] and convert them to the "S" if they are near of the given location (Args are "K,K,K,Y-K,Y,M,M-K,Y,Y,Y 2,1 S" if you need)

```
public class MatrixRefill {
    public static String[][] matrix;
    public static int rows;
    public static int cols;
    public static String enemy;      
    public static String target;        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        target = args[2];
        rows = Integer.parseInt(args[1].substring(0,1));
        cols = Integer.parseInt(args[1].substring(2));
        matrix = matrixCreator(args[0]);
        enemy = matrix[rows][cols];
        recursive(rows, cols, target);
        printer(matrix);
    }
    public static String[][] matrixCreator(String mx) {
        int ro = 0;
        int co = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mx.length(); i++) {
            if (mx.substring(i,i+1).equals(","))
                co++;
            if (mx.substring(i,i+1).equals("-"))
                ro++;
        }
        String[][] matriks = new String[ro+1][co/3+1];
        ro = 0;
        co = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < mx.length(); j++) {
            if (mx.substring(j,j+1).equals(","))
                co++;
            else if (mx.substring(j,j+1).equals("-")) {
                ro++;
                co = 0;
            }
            else
                matriks[ro][co] = mx.substring(j,j+1);
        }
        return matriks;
    }   
    public static void recursive(int row, int col, String target) {
        if (valid(row,col)) {
            recursive(row+1,col, target);
            recursive(row,col+1, target);
            recursive(row,col-1, target);
            recursive(row-1,col, target);
            matrix[row][col] = target;
        }
    }
    public static boolean valid(int row, int col) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (row >= 0 && row < matrix.length && col >= 0 && col < matrix[row].length)
            if (matrix[row][col] == enemy)
                result = true;
        return result;
    }
    public static void printer(String[][] owo) {
        for(int i = 0; i < owo.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < owo[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(owo[i][j]);
                if(j < owo[i].length - 1)
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the static keyword from your methods and instance fields.  But to call them from within `main` you need to create an `instance` of the containing class (in this case the one that contains the `main` method) and use that to call the other methods.  What I do sometimes is to create an instance method (i.e. non-static) and call that to start the process.  Then everything that would be in main I would put in that method.  Here is an example.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MatrixRefill mr = new MatrixRefill();
        mr.start();
    }
    public void start() {
        target = args[2];
        rows = Integer.parseInt(args[1].substring(0,1));
        cols = Integer.parseInt(args[1].substring(2));
        matrix = matrixCreator(args[0]);
        enemy = matrix[rows][cols];
        recursive(rows, cols, target);
        printer(matrix);
    }
    // rest of code here
}
```

By putting what was in `main` in the `start` method you can call the other instance methods and access instance fields without qualifying them with a reference to the class (i.e. in this case prefixing with `mr.`)

Comment: "_create an instance of the containing class_" - as a complete beginner I remember it took me a while for this concept (and its wider implications) to really sink in.